# Setting paging to 10 of Default JPA CRUD (List.jsp)

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, netbeans, persistence

How to change default number paging from 5 to 10 in JPA CRUD JSF

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Please post some code. How would we know what to change?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://anydoby.com/jblog/en/java/45) might be help.